# Paypal custom field not propergating

Tags: paypal

I have set up a sandbox for paypal with a buyer and a seller. I have created a button for a subscription and pasted the code into my website along with the custom hidden field with the value ofv 121. In the Optional Fields I added "custom=0" as just adding "custom" alone would not save.

I processed the payment and checked the returned post for the custom variable in the $_REQUEST() string and it was not their, how do I get at it. What I got was bellow:

```
http://www.socialise4fun.co.uk/success.php?auth=Cjr-longstring-OSBx...&form_charset=UTF-8
```

What do I do with it to get my data back.

I'm trying to pass through the user_id in the custom field that paypal says in many places you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use IPN to receive this data. This data is not supposed to be available in the GET of the return URL.

Have a look at https://www.paypal.com/ipn/

In short: include `<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://link-to-your-IPN-script">` in your PayPal button, and you'll receive a POST with this data once the transaction has gone through.